# ASP MVC EF Update/Insert data in related tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relational-database

I have following 3 models for related database tables. I can display these on a single View with 3 tables having inputs for each record; I can create js object with all records and can send to the controller; How do I update records in the database? Note that i can handle master,  detail data in controller but in this case i have master,  master,  and detail with multiple rows...

```
public partial class LocLocations1//Masters of Masters
{
    public LocLocations1()
    {
        LocLocations2 = new HashSet<LocLocations2>();


    }

    public int LocID { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
    public Boolean Activated { get; set; }
    public Boolean AdminLock { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<LocLocations2> LocLocations2 { get; set; }

}


public partial class LocLocations2//Masters
{
    public LocLocations2()
    {
        LocLocations3 = new HashSet<LocLocations3>();
    }

    public int LocID { get; set; }
    public int MasterLocID { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
    public short? Activated { get; set; }
    public short? AdminLock { get; set; }

    public virtual LocLocations1 LocLocations1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<LocLocations3> LocLocations3 { get; set; }
}

public partial class LocLocations3//Details
{

    public int LocID { get; set; }
    public int MasterLocID { get; set; }
    public string LocName { get; set; }
    public short? Activated { get; set; }
    public short? AdminLock { get; set; }

    public virtual LocLocations2 LocLocations2 { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Please refer to the following, to update related data in MVC with EF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

First select the record and related record to edit:

```
using (var dataContext = new DBContextModel())
{
   var locLocations1 = dataContext.LocLocations1_DBSet.SingleOrDefault(s => s.LocID == id_param);
   var locLocations2 = locLocations1.LocLocations2.SingleOrDefault(s => s.LocID == id_param_from_ViewModel);

   //update values and save changes to DB
   locLocations2.Activated = 1;
   locLocations2.AdminLock = 1;  
   locLocations1.AdminLock = true;               
   dataContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Likewise you can select from the other related model and update data.